# A stock rom for Samsung Captivate?

Tags: odin, stock-rom, samsung-captivate

I need to flash a stock ROM to my Samsung Captivate i897 as a part of unbricking process, but I can't find one. Odin one click roms don't work for me as Odin one click doesn't see my phone (regular ODIN does see the phone so I assume the drivers are ok). I need a rom that I can either install in recovery or using regular ODIN

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other question. I went to all the sites mentioned and haven't found any up-to-date links to stock ROMs for captivate (i897)

Answer (score 0):

For samsung stock ROM download log on to http://samsung-updates.com/latest-firmware/

1. Choose your Device
2. Choose ROM
3. Download and then Flash it

Done

Comment: +1. Also http://www.sammobile.com has all the stock firmwares. I would just add for the OP: always ensure you have EVERYTHING downloaded in advance of installing anything. Have a `nandroid` backup made and on your PC, the ROM you will be flashing, any other tools you need.

Comment: Unfotunately neither sammobile.com nor samsung-updates.com have any ROMs for Captivate (i897).